# ARIMA model with multiple covariates, XREG

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, predictor

I have shared the main data d2015.txt, includes 5 columns. The first column is the $y_t$ the time series observation. The  2nd to the 4th column is the covariates/regressors and the fifth column is the mean of the three covariates. The main file shared in my [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nBXTrGPAC05xVCBpIeaKaiB-S6mjbQDV/view?usp=sharing).

I used this code to fit an ARIMA model in which "ur" is univariate time series of observation and the "gt" is a multivariate covariates dataset with 3 columns:

```
> fit2 = auto.arima(ur,xreg=gt)
```

the output is:

```
Series: ur 
Regression with ARIMA(1,1,0) errors 

Coefficients:
         ar1    drift   Apply  office  resume
      0.5109  -0.1562  0.0098  0.0001  -5e-04
s.e.  0.1141   0.0277  0.0013  0.0017   9e-04

sigma^2 estimated as 0.01239:  log likelihood=50.62
AIC=-89.24   AICc=-87.71   BIC=-76.48

Training set error measures:
                      ME    RMSE        MAE        MPE      MAPE     MASE        ACF1
Training set 0.002114705 0.10588 0.08902272 0.04035552 0.5226742 0.497244 -0.06112877
```

My first question is: how to formulate this ARIMA into mathematical writing?

> $Y_t$= ???

I used `pred2 = forecast(fit2,h=1, xreg=gt)`to forecast the next month, but it predicts for more months!!! Why? Can you correct me, pls?

[image]

Comment: In most ARIMA model with covariate discussed on the Internet, there is one covariate, but in my model there is about 10 covariates, $X_i$. What do you suggest to do?

Answer (score 2):

1. Note that `auto.arima()` fits a regression with ARIMA errors, not an ARIMAX model. [There is a difference.](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) Thus, your model is

   $$ y_t=X_t\beta+\epsilon_t,$$

   where $X_t$ contains your regressors at time $t$, and

   $$ \epsilon_t\sim\text{ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift,} $$

   or

   $$ (\epsilon_t-\epsilon_{t-1}) = \gamma t+\phi(\epsilon_{t-1}-\epsilon_{t-2})+\eta_t.$$

   $\gamma$ is estimated by your `drift` parameter and $\phi$ by the `ar1` one.
2. You can find what is happening in `?forecast.Arima` (note the capital `A`), under the entry for `h` in the `Arguments` section:

   > If ‘xreg’ is used, ‘h’ is ignored and the number of forecast periods is set to the number of rows of ‘xreg’.

   Of course, you need to supply the new regressors when forecasting, and then the number of rows in this new regressor matrix is used to determine the forecasting horizon. However, you are using the regressors `gt` you used in fitting for forecasting. You probably don't want to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Kolassa. I tested my data with ARIMAX, as advised, but the same problem occurred!!

Comment: What problem are you referring to?

Comment: Dear @Stephan_Kolassa
In fact, I have 63 observation ($Y_t$) and 63 values for 4 covariates ($X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$). With {auto.arima(ur,xreg=gt)} the ARIMA (1,1,0) is proposed. BUT the problem is: 

How to forecast or predict for the next 5 months?

Comment: Create a `matrix` containing the regressor values for the 5 months you want to forecast. (It may be necessary that the column names match the ones in the original `gt`.) Then feed this matrix to the `xreg` parameter of `forecast()`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. 
That's a great solution! But if i don't have any figure for that matrix, how can I go ahead? is there any function to predict newXreg from the past Xreg?

Comment: Well, if your time series depends on certain drivers or predictors, then you can't predict meaningfully without future values of the drivers. The common approach would be to forecast the drivers themselves in some way. For instance, retail sales depend on the weather, so if we want to include weather in the forecast, we need to include weather forecasts. Note that of course there is uncertainty in these driver forecasts, so you can't just take prediction intervals from the model for the forecasted drivers at face value.